# what is a connection between two simple yet important economics and math formula: elasticity

Tags: calculus, math-history, economics

what makes it interesing to define them in mathematics? what is a connection between two simple yet important economics and math formula: elasticity?

Something interesting to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_a_function